# How do I structure a Timer in an external class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am trying to create a new stopwatch timer.

I have my:

- Main Timer ViewController
- a timer Model - where I store my timer.

When my timer finishes in my model how can I let the main ViewController know that it's been completed? 
Ideally I would like to run a function the main UIViewController when the timer is completed in the model.

```
Class myTimer: NSObject {
    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        print("timer Stopped at \(currentTime)")
    }
}
```

Comment: hi - the other ways seemed to be quite complex. and to use the NSNotification seemed like over kill for communication between 1 class and  1 model.  I just added my ViewController as a parameter to the model, so they can update each other.  I will probably refactor to make it simpler in the longterm, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this by posting, registering and deallocating notifications.

-registering for notifications, do this in viewDidLoad of viewController.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "timerExpired", name: "TimerCompleteNotification", object: nil)
```

where selector is the function to call when the timer complete notification is posted.

-posting notifications. Add this in whatever function updates the timer label and calls this when the timer expires.

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("TimerCompleteNotification", object: nil)
```

Just make sure "TimerCompleteNotification" is the spelled the same in both posting and addObserver. What you are doing here is saying, "I'd like to observe a notification that may happen, and when it does, I'll call this function," And then when the timer ends, you post that notification and perform the designated function.

Forgot to tell you to add this to your view controller or you will get an access error

```
deinit{

        //Unregister for notificationsd
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)

    }
```

Comment: This was a good solution, even though I didn't actually end up using it.  Thanks for the detail- I will use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have your MyTimer class do exactly the kind of thing an NSTimer already does. The "user" of MyTimer registers a callback function when it creates / starts MyTimer, and the MyTimer calls that function when it fires.

Comment: Here's my example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p499timerLeaker2/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/CancelableTimer.swift